# How to use Nuxt.js with socket.io/socket.io.-client?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io, nuxt.js

I am new to **nuxt.js** and **socket.io**. I have been studying it for a while i am got stuck between socket.io and socket.io-client. I will getting data from API (which is php) so should i use only socket.io-client for my front end? or Do i need both?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I use it it my app as a plugin:

Define it in socket.js file like this:

```
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client';
import VueSocketIoExtended from 'vue-socket.io-extended';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default ({ store, env }) => {
    const socket = SocketIO(env.socketUrl, {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        reconnection: true,
        reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
        autoConnect: true,
    });

    Vue.use(VueSocketIoExtended, socket, { store });
};
```

then you can include it in nuxt.config.js as plugin:

```
  plugins: [
        { src: '~/socket.js', mode: 'client' },
    ],
```

More info about socket library here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io-extended

Comment: In the plugin it is mentioned that if i don't make ssr false in the nuxt.config.js it will crash... But my app is using Universal mode which is SSR